# Does the Bible ever describe the Fall in ways different than Genesis 3?

Tags: biblical-basis, original-sin, fall-of-man

In his book *In the Beginning*, Cardinal Joseph Ratzinger wrote the following with regards to the pre-Pauline hymn of Phil 2:5-11:

> We cannot consider this extraordinarily rich and profound text [Phil
>   2:5-11] in detail. We want to limit ourselves here to its connection
>   with the story of the Fall, even though **it seems to have a somewhat
>   different version in mind** than the one that is related in Genesis 3
>   (cf., e.g., Job 15:7-8).

What is the account of the Fall presumed by Phil 2:5-11? And what is the account of the Fall related in Job 15:7-8?

More over, are there other places where the Bible gives an account of original sin (either explicitly or implicitly)? If this question is too involved, I would be satisfied by any book/article recommendations.

Comment: Yes, if you will accept the vision of Ven. Mary of Agreda and Blessed Emmerich, the Genesis3 story will be alot more easier to understand.

Comment: Romans 5:12-21 is a comprehensive expression of how sin entered the world. But this is a very broad subject and would only be trivialised if it were not treated in its deserved detail.

Comment: Nigel J, the account in Romans 5:12-21 seems to mirror Genesis 3. Ratzinger, however, seems to believe that Phil 2:5-11 and Job 15:7-8 (and perhaps other passages) presume an explanation of the Fall distinct from Genesis 3.

Comment: @Doubt it seems to me that the fall implied by Phil 2:5-11 and Job 15:7-8 correspond to the fall of Satan rather than the one of Adam. Satan has fallen first (probably a long time before Adam) and then he made Adam fall. Refs of Satan's fall can be found in Isa 14:12-14 and also Ezek 28:11-17